# Output the Names of Copied Files in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, output

I am working on a bash script to copy configuration files to their appropriate directories. I would like to output the name of the file that I have copied to the user. Here is what I have so far:

```
CONFIG_DIR="/home/stackoverflow/app/configs"
CONFIG_FILE="*.config"

cp $CONFIG_FILE $CONFIG_DIR

echo "$CONFIG_FILE was copied to $CONFIG_DIR"
```

The output I get from this is:

```
*.config was copied to /home/stackoverflow/app/configs
```

Let's assume that stackoverflow.config is the only .config file present in the directory where the script is running. I would like it to say:

```
stackoverflow.config was copied to /home/stackoverflow/app/configs
```

Comment: The output of `cp -v` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either add -v to copy and have it print all the file names (one name per line) or change the echo to

```
echo $CONFIG_FILE was copied to $CONFIG_DIR
```

i.e. remove the double quotes (they are not necessary in this example).

Answer (score 3):

Move the `$CONFIG` outside the quotes, in order to allow the shell to expand its wildcards:

```
echo $CONFIG_FILE "was copied to $CONFIG_DIR"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONFIG_DIR="/home/stackoverflow/app/configs"
for file in *.config
do
    cp $file $CONFIG_DIR
    echo $file was copied to $CONFIG_DIR
done
```